# How to convert a raw data array into a BufferedImage

Tags: java

I have an int[2048][2048] raw data array of a tiff image in java. I want to convert that array back into a BufferedImage. How should I proceed?

Comment: Is it raw data or a TIFF now? Straigthen out the ambigous question to get good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say *raw data* this does not tell anything about the format of the data, I'm assuming that it will be in the most common format: ARGB. Turning it into a BufferedImage then can be done by simply transferring every pixel using the BufferedImage.setRGB() method:

```
public static BufferedImage toBufferedImage(int[][] rawRGB) {
    int h = rawRGB.length;
    int w = rawRGB[0].length;
    BufferedImage i = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    for (int y=0; y<h; ++y) {
        for (int x=0; x<w; ++x) {
            int argb = rawRGB[y][x];
            i.setRGB(x, y, argb);
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

You get the idea, just copy pixel by pixel into the BufferedImage.

If the image seems to be mirrored in one or both dimensions, you need to correct for that in the setRGB call with (w-x-1, h-y-1) respectively.
If the image seems to be rotated, create the image with w and h swapped and setRGB(y, x, argb).
If the colors appear inverted/garbled, find out the channel order in the argb value and shift it accordingly to make the channel order A, R, G, B. The pixels may also be in a totally different color model - you need to find out what color model they are in and transform each pixel to ARGB.

The method you obtained the array from *should* provide some documentation how the data is organized.

Answer (score 3):

As simple as this:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(array));
```

Comment: ByteArrayInputStream accepts an array of bytes as an argument, but what I have is an int[][] array